# SharePoint 2013 REST API AJAX update workflow task

Tags: workflow

I need your help.
I'd like to complete custom workflow task, (SH 2010 WF) running over 2013. 
I've been using a pice of code. to update a task list using Rest API in JavaScript AJAX.
I test this code with other list and run OK, but When I like to update a task list. I received different error MSG.

If I like to updated Title filed I received ""message":{"lang":"es-ES","value":"Value does not fall within the expected range."}}},"status":400,"statusText":"Bad Request"}"

If I like to Update Result field I can see the filed in properties.

Do you have any conceptual description about how to work with workflow task and their content types using Rest API

Thank in advance
Ramiro

I'll share my code.

```
function updateJson(endpointUri,payload, success, error) 
{          
    return getFormDigest('https://partner.coca-cola.com/sites/SLBU2013Test/POC').then(function (data) {
        $.ajax({       
           url: endpointUri,   
           type: "POST",   
           data: JSON.stringify(payload),
           contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
           headers: { 
              "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
              "X-RequestDigest" :  data.d.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue,
              "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
               "If-Match": "*"
           },   
           success: success,
           error: error
        });
    });
}

function getItemTypeForListName(name) {
    console.log("SP.Data." + name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.slice(1) + "ListItem");

    return"SP.Data." + name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.slice(1) + "ListItem";

}

function updateListItem(webUrl,listTitle,listItemId,itemProperties,success,failure)
{

         var listItemUri =  webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/items(" + listItemId + ")";
         console.log(listItemUri);
         var itemPayload = {
             '__metadata': {'type': 'SP.Data.TasksListItem'}
           };
         for(var prop in itemProperties){
               itemPayload[prop] = itemProperties[prop];
               console.log(itemProperties[prop]);
         }
         updateJson(listItemUri,itemPayload,success,failure);

}

function getFormDigest(webUrl) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: webUrl + "/_api/contextinfo",
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" }
    });
}

function Calcular (){

    var itemProperties = {'Status':'Completadas'};
    updateListItem('https://partner.coca-cola.com/sites/SLBU2013Test/POC','Tasks',2,itemProperties,printInfo,logError);
    function printInfo()
    {
        console.log('Item has been created');
    }
    function logError(error){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    }

};
```

Comment: We are having the same problem.  Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

There is another similar post.  My answer there was to do some screen scraping and redirect users to the UI.  Short story is that we could not update the list with REST, but could with CSOM.  Regardless, the WF ignored the task changes.  Here's the link: [Update task item programatically in Sharepoint with CSOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25744010/update-task-item-programatically-in-sharepoint-with-csom/39027013#39027013).